# How to display a tree view of all assets?

Tags: templating, assets, ordering

I like to display a tree-like view of all files in an asset source:

- Folder_X

  - File_A
  - File_B
  - Folder_Y

    - File_C
- Folder_Z

  - ...

I know that I can iterate over all assets in a source (`{% for file in craft.assets.sourceId('1') %}`) but this gives just an alphabetically sorted list of all files. Maybe we need something like the [nav-tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/nav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the [Assets Browser Plugin](https://gum.co/AssetsBroswer) which allows to browse an asset source or a specific folder on the frontend.

Although it is not a treeview it serves me well for outputting a download area on the website. It works even with the [Internal Assets Plugin](https://github.com/tikiatua/internal-assets-plugin) for a member-only area.

Answer (score 1):

Yoursort, my answer was based on the assumption that the AssetsService could be used in templates. Ofcourse, only the variables can be used.

I don't have time to dive into this (now), but I think your best bet is to get all images, use [`asset.folder'](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel#folder) for each asset and 'rebuild' the hierarchical list of folder and their assets. Again, use [cache](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache) ;)